# How can I implement user registration batch processing before load test execution in Locust?

Tags: python, locust

I am currently running the account registration batch process before running the load test and then running the task.
It works in standalone, but in master and worker configuration, it does not work well because the process is split.
How can I implement this kind of use case?

- requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.1.2
gevent==21.1.2
greenlet==1.0.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
locust==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
msgpack==1.0.2
pyzmq==22.0.3
requests==2.25.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

- running script

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCUST=$(which locust)
LOCUS_OPTS="-f ${LOCUST_FILE:-locustfile.py} --host=${TARGET_HOST:-http://localhost:9080}"

if [[ "$LOCUST_MODE" = "master" ]]; then
    LOCUS_OPTS="$LOCUS_OPTS --master"
elif [[ "$LOCUST_MODE" = "worker" ]]; then
    LOCUS_OPTS="$LOCUS_OPTS --worker --master-host=$LOCUST_MASTER"
fi

$LOCUST $LOCUS_OPTS
```

- locustfile.py

```
from locust import (
    between,
    task,
    events
)
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpUser

token_list = []

@events.test_start.add_listener
def on_test_start(environment, **kwargs):
    global token_list

    logging.info("A new test is starting")
    account_list = []

    base_user_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    user_count = environment.runner.target_user_count
    idx = 0
    max_count = 499
    path = f'{environment.host}/v1/accounts'

    for _ in range(((user_count - 1) // max_count) + 1):
        num = min(max_count, user_count)
        external_user_ids = [f'{base_user_id}_{n}' for n in range(idx, idx + num)]

        payload = create_initial_account_api_request(external_user_ids)
        access_token = create_initial_token()
        response = requests.post(path, json=payload, headers=access_token)

        logging.info("Response status code:", response.status_code)
        logging.info("Response content:", response.text)
        res_json = response.json()
        account_list += res_json['response']
        idx += num
        user_count -= num

    auth_header = make_auth_header()
    path = f'{environment.host}/v1/oauth/token'

    for account in account_list:
        account_body = account['body']
        external_user_id = account_body['external_user_id']
        payload = create_initial_user_token_api_request(external_user_id)
        response = requests.post(
            path, data=payload, headers=auth_header)

        logging.info("Response status code:", response.status_code)
        logging.info("Response content:", response.text)

        token_list.append(response.json())


@events.test_stop.add_listener
def on_test_stop(environment, **kwargs):
    global token_list
    token_list = []


class MyUser(FastHttpUser):
    wait_time = between(3, 6)

    def on_start(self):
        global token_list

        token_data = token_list.pop()
        logging.info("Account data:", str(token_data))
        self.account_id = token_data['account_id']
        self.refresh_token = token_data['refresh_token']
        self.access_token = token_data['access_token']

    @task
    def normal_task(self):
        self.refresh_task()
        self.first_task()
        self.second_task()
        # ...

    # tasks
```